# Hypothetical Question: In-Car Hands Free Microphone - Unlimited Budget - What Would You Do?

Tags: cars, vehicles, noise-reduction, noise

Hello,

Totally hypothetical question:

A wealthy man approaches asks you to design the optimal microphone solution for an in-car hands-free calling system.

He has three goals:
A: eliminate background noise
B: eliminate feedback
C: optimize voice quality

He has only three constraints:
A: the solution must use fewer than two microphones
B: it must plug into the 'mic-in' on the hands-free system using a 3.5 MM male connector
C: you can not adjust the audio-out
C: the solution must not be visually intrusive (he welcomes your interpretation of 'intrusive')

The wealthy man provides you with all the money, time, expertise, and equipment you require?

What would you build?

Answer (score 1):

Lav mic mounted in sun visor, PZM/PCC mounted on windscreen.  Subtract out of phase output from PZM/PCC from lav (direct sound) to partially phase cancel indirect sound within car.

Comment: yeah this or something incredibly similar would be my solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get DPA to do the work. Their lav's are amazing,as are their headsets. I'm sure they can make it noise cancel.

Answer (score 0):

given the goals, a headset mic is probably the optimal solution.  Noise is best minimized with proximity, and nothing's closer to your mouth than a headset mic.

Its why all of the sports anchors wear them when they're out on location in the midst of a rowdy crowd.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do exactly what you're doing. Well, the first bit anyways.

Pose the question to a bunch of experts, find a good solutions, hire the expert/s to work for you, take a cut. (^_^)/

Answer (score 0):

SM7B type capsule shock mounted within the steering wheel. all gyroscopes and suspended :P